# SonarLint in Eclipse (connected mode) does not show any issues when SonarQube does

Tags: sonarlint-eclipse

I have a set of projects in my Eclipse workspace bound to SonarQube modules that are part of a project which (according to SonarQube) uses a custom Quality Profile for Java that we created locally.

When I open (in Eclipse) a Java source file that has several issues listed in SonarQube, the "on the fly" SonarLint analysis shows zero issues found. One of the issues listed in SonarQube is squid:S1200, which I would expect to also be highlighted in SonarLint, but is not.

Can someone help me find the problem in our local setup that is preventing SonarLint from highlighting the issues found by SonarQube?

Environment:

Eclipse
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

Java
openjdk version "1.8.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

SonarLint for Eclipse
3.2.0.201707271328

SonarQube 5.6.7